# Forced conversion of non-numeric numpy arrays with NAN replacement

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion, nan, coercion

Consider the array

`x = np.array(['1', '2', 'a'])`

Tying to convert to a float array raises an exception

```
x.astype(np.float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: a
```

Does numpy provide any efficient way to coerce this into a numeric array, replacing non-numeric values with something like NAN?

Alternatively, is there an efficient numpy function equivalent to `np.isnan`, but which also tests for non-numeric elements like letters?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert an array of strings into an array of floats (with NaNs) using [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

```
In [83]: np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)

In [84]: np.genfromtxt(np.array(['1','2','3.14','1e-3','b','nan','inf','-inf']))
Out[84]: array([ 1.   ,  2.   ,  3.14 ,  0.001,    nan,    nan,    inf,   -inf])
```

---

Here is a way to identify "numeric" strings:

```
In [34]: x
Out[34]: 
array(['1', '2', 'a'], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [35]: x.astype('unicode')
Out[35]: 
array([u'1', u'2', u'a'], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [36]: np.char.isnumeric(x.astype('unicode'))
Out[36]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Note that "numeric" means a unicode that contains only digit characters -- that is, characters that have the Unicode numeric value property. It does **not** include the decimal point. So `u'1.3'` is not considered "numeric".

Comment: This answer might need revision for python3 - You'd get `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Thanks for the heads-up. Fixed with `astype('bytes')`.

Comment: No problem. Great answer as always, thanks for the knowledge sharing!

Comment: Works nowadays without conversion to bytes

Comment: If the list contains both strings and numbers, you can use `np.genfromtxt(np.array(x, dtype=str))`

Answer (score 10):

If you happen to be using pandas as well you could use the [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) method:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: x = np.array(['1', '2', 'a'])

In [4]: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')
Out[4]: array([  1.,   2.,  nan])
```