# How to convert a numpy array into a float array (with exception handling)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume that I have the following list:

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1,    1.1, 'a'],
     ['ab', '1', '1.1']]
a_np = np.array(a)
print(a_np)

>>> [['1' '1.1' 'a']
    ['ab' '1' '1.1']]
```

I would like to turn `a_np` into an array of `np.float64` values.  However...

```
print(np.float64(a_np))
>>> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'
```

...some of these values are not able to be turned into floats.

Is there a pythonic way to turn the array into an array of floats while turning the rest of the values into `np.nan` objects?

Desired:

```
print(pythonic_float_function(a_np))
>>> [[ 1.   1.1  nan]
    [ nan  1.   1.1]]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223483/forced-conversion-of-non-numeric-numpy-arrays-with-nan-replacement

Comment: If you use pandas, `pd.to_numeric(..., errors='coerce')` works well.

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(a_np.reshape(-1, ), errors='coerce').reshape(a_np.shape)`