# find out indices where numeric condition is met when data is str

Tags: python, numpy

I have this array

```
x = np.array([['1', 'Nb v'],
              ['2', '2'],
              ['3', 'Nb v'],
              ['4','3']])
```

I want to find out the indices where the second column is greater than 2 .
That is the 3rd index (last line).

Because data are string, I can't just convert from string to int because I have problem with `Nb v`.

So, I thought to find out the indices where I don't have the word `Nb v`.

```
idx, = np.where(x[:, 1] != 'Nb v')
```

gives :

```
array([1, 3])
```

and then find the indices where  value is greater than 2:

```
new_idx, = np.where(x[idx, 1].astype(int) > 2)
```

gives :

```
array([1])
```

but that gives the index of `idx` where this happens, not the index of `x`.

I want to find out the index/indices of `x` where the second column is `> 2`.

Comment: if you can use `pandas` as well, go have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537877/9274732) for converting the column to `int` with `pandas.to_numeric` and then you can use `np.where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if the string can be converted to an integer or not.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([['1', 'Nb v'],['2', '2'],['3', 'Nb v'],['4','3']])


for i,j in enumerate(x):
    try:
        a=int(j[1])
        if a>2:
            print(i)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

A pure NumPy method, you can use [`np.char.isnumeric`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.isnumeric.html) and `np.where` twice:

```
x_slice = x[:, 1]
x_int = np.where(np.char.isnumeric(x_slice), x_slice, 0).astype(int)
idx = np.where(x_int > 2.0)[0]

array([3], dtype=int64)
```

Or use `np.where` following by indexing:

```
x_numeric = np.where(np.char.isnumeric(x[:, 1]))[0]
idx = x_numeric[x[x_numeric, 1].astype(int) > 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `np.where` the second time, you can slice directly `idx`:

```
idx, = np.where(x[:, 1] != 'Nb v')
print (idx[x[idx, 1].astype(int) > 2])
# array([3], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks!Nice solution, upv